# c# Clipboard.GetImage() from Photoshop region returns a b/w image

Tags: c#, image, photoshop

If I copy a region from Photoshop in RGB 8 bits the `Clipboard.GetImage()` has a black and white image, but if I change it to an indexed mode (256) `GetImage` returns a colored image.

I've also tried with the `GetDataObject` method, but with same results. It seems the image format is memoryBMP but in RGB/8 format so I can't get the full colored image.

How to retrieve color image from Photoshop clipboard format back into my C# app?

This is the code I'm using. The image is saved, but..

- If I copy pixels from an image in Photoshop mode `RGB/8` it save as b/w.
- If mode is `index` (256 colors) it saves color.

The image format in data is of type :

```
[ImageFormat: b96b3caa-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e] MemoryBMP
```

Following is my C# code...

```
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Dib))
{
    Bitmap image = (System.Drawing.Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Dib, false) as Bitmap;

    var encoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
    var encParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 24L);
    image.Save("encode.jpg", encoder, encParams);
}
```

Comment: I did not downvote but I think you must **show some testable code** to allow others to re-create and/or fix your problem... PS: Remember RGB 8-bit is really a total of 24 bits colour (since 8 bits for red + 8 for green + 8 for blue). If that helps you in some way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My first post, learning the rules...

Comment: There is a small [**`edit`**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46576473/edit) button under your post. Or else just use link (add `/edit` to page url) : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46576473/edit

Comment: Test my answer and if it works for you, then [**mark as solved**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) to help others who need this correct answer too. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be the actual data comes as BGRA instead of ARGB, and I forget to mention I'm doing this in Unity3D

Comment: _"Data comes as BGRA instead of ARGB"_ sounds like an [**Endianness issue**](https://conquertheworldbycode.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/20110628-070206.jpg). Are you compiling on PC or Mac? From Windows using Photoshop (8-bits per R-G-B channel of each pixel) I got 3 bytes `[R] [G] [B]` (no alpha) in C# clipboard. I don't know how you got 4 channels and reverse order from clipboard. Unity might not be issue since your shown bitmap uses C# APIs to get image and save image, no pixels adjusted by Unity code.

Comment: After the `Bitmap image = (data.GetData...` line, add newline of `MessageBox.Show("Format is : " + image.pixelFormat, "Hello Alexeef.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);` ... What does it say your format is? Also confirm if compiling on PC or Mac.

Comment: Um. Fetching the data for DataFormats.Dib shouldn't return a Bitmap object at all; it's supposed to be a byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just select a rectangle area in **Photoshop** (or any image program, like **Paint** etc) then paste that into your app (via get from Clipboard)...

Try it like this :

```
//# Get copied data (image) from clipboard
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Dib))
{
    //# Make into C# bitmap
    Bitmap image = (data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap,true) as Bitmap);

    //# Show in some PictureBox
    //pbx.Image = image;

    //# Save to disk
    image.Save("c:/test//encode_test1.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

- Compile and run your app (its window should be open).
- In Photoshop.. open an image and select/copy an area.
- In your app, get the image brought in (I used keypress to run `function` of above code).
- Find the JPG file at `C:\` drive inside the `test` folder.
- If you created a`PictureBox` object you can even view *"selected area"* image within your app.